# Как вычислить windows server через python, на pyqt5?

Tags: python, pyqt5

Подскажите как возможно вычислить windows server через python приложение? Обычное получение платформы через sys видит по факту одно и тоже и на windows server и на том же windows 10. А так же далее необходимо научиться определять что программа запускается на virtual box. Подскажите есть ли такая возможность у python или pyqt5? Или только косвенными признаками как то можно определить? И если да то какими? Спасибо!

Comment: А скажите, пожалуйста, какая основная задача?

Comment: Если у вас на виртуалбокс тест, а на другом сервере прод - то различить сервера можно либо по IP либо по имени компьютера.

Comment: Нужно именно определять сервера и виртуалки

Comment: Задача - чтобы моя программа не запускалась на серверах или виртуалках.

Answer (score 2):

Мак адрес сетевой карточки проверьте, если там что то вроде `52:54:00:69:08:95`, то скорее всег вы на виртуалке. Смотри вторую цифру:

```
x2:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
x6:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
xA:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
xE:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
```

Или на компьютере стоит виртуальный адаптер openvpn / hamanchi. Также такой мак будет определяться на усб модемах. поэтому смотрим первый сетевой адаптер только.